# Failing to create floating table of contents with rmarkdown in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, tableofcontents

I'm failing to create a free floating table of content using `rmarkdown` rendered as `html`. Here's the text:

````
---
title: "example"
date: "22 January 2019"
output: 
  html_document:
  toc: true
  toc_float: true
  toc_collapsed: true
---

```library(rmarkdown)```
```library(knitr)```


##<span style="color:darkgreen">1. XXX</span>

```c("a", "b", "c")```

```{r}
````

Then I render the document as `html` using `render("example.Rmd",html_document())`. The document is created correctly, except that it does not contain a floating table of contents. Is there a problem with this syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Indentation in the YAML header is important:

```
---
title: "example"
date: "22 January 2019"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_collapsed: true
---
```

Comment: Works fine for me though. You may want to add a space after the `##` and before `<span ....`